# Do I have to set back rdbuf

Tags: c++

The purpose of this code is to support running my code either by `./a.out < input_file_name` or just `./a.out input_file_name`. I know I can wrap my reading part into a separate function with a parameter `iostream&`, so I can pass either `ifstream` or `cin` depending on whether `argc == 2`.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
if (argc != 1 && argc != 2) {
    cerr << "usage file or <file" << endl;
}

ifstream in;
if (argc == 2) {
    in.open(argv[1]);
    cin.rdbuf(in.rdbuf());
}

string line;
while (getline(cin, line))
    cout << line << "\n";
}
```

My above trivial code always use `cin` read stuff. Do I need to set `cin` back to its original `rdbuf`?

Some code examples I found always set back `rdbuf` to its original value. Do we have to? Is there any resource leak when changing cin or cout's rdbuf without setting back its original rdbuf later?

Comment: I question why you wrote your code like this in the first place. Why not simply `getline(in, line)`?

Comment: did you see that if no argument is passed, my code will read standard input instead?

Comment: There are much better ways to accomplish that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You correctly suggest to wrap reading into a separate function, that gets either `in` or `cin` passed as parameter. That would be the best solution.

Besides that, to answer your question: You are not required to set it back; but you might harm other users this way. It's very unexpected, to read from some file using `cin`. The following users using `cin` in your program will have a hard time using `cin` as normal. If you want to keep your code, you probably should set it back.

Why not just do the following (leaving `cin` aside completely):

```
ifstream in;
if (argc > 2) {
    in.open(argv[1]);
}
istream & input = (argc > 2 ? in : cin);

string line;
while (getline(input, line))
    cout << line << "\n";
```

Comment: Did I miss something? I can't see where 'in' gets used, or how 'cin' gets linked to 'in'.

Comment: @Derek: You are right, my fault. I've corrected my answer. `cin` is intentionally unused.

Comment: how does your code work if i run program like ./a.out < file_name ?

Comment: @Derek: I was expecting `./a.out filename`. I see the problem, you want to do both. I'll edit again. You will not need to set anything back, still...

Comment: thanks. It's nice to assign a reference from a ternary operator:)

Answer (score 0):

### Quick answer:

> Yes, if it's going to be used again before the end of the program.

You should probably save the original `std::cin.rdbuf()`, then redirect it to do you job and finally restore its original value.

Just use this line before redirection:

```
std::streambuf *cinbuf = std::cin.rdbuf();
```

and then this to reset:

```
std::cin.rdbuf(cinbuf);
```

Comment: I do not mind to do it, but I guess it should be done in RAII to be completely safe, which means need to have a small class/struct or some sort of lambda for the job.